# my django website says "We're sorry, but something went wrong" in production

Tags: python, django, server, production-environment

my django website was working in debuging mode but when I put it on the server and turned it to production mode, my website shows me the error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. The issue has been logged for
>   investigation. Please try again later.

I have checked out my settings, my passenger_wsgi.py file and I wrote it it this line

```
from myproject.wsgi import application
```

and also run the followed commands

```
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
```

cpanel Error log says

```
[ E 2019-05-09 08:11:44.4868 967877/T1m age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/muntadar/creepy-surprise: The application process exited prematurely.
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 66, in <module>
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/levels/models.py", line 3, in <module>
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/creepy_surprise/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
 App 978910 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
 [ E 2019-05-08 20:20:46.4873 828707/T1r age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/muntadar/creepy-surprise: The application process exited prematurely.
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 66, in <module>
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/levels/models.py", line 3, in <module>
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/creepy_surprise/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/creepy-surprise/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
 App 885800 output:
   File "/home/muntadar/virtualenv/creepy-surprise/3.7/lib64/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
```

and the problem still exist
what else can I do?

.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: review the question

Comment: Please use a code block for ascii text output such as a logfile. Quoted text is unreadable for output like this.

Comment: Does it work in production mode with the development server?

Comment: What is line 3 of levels/models.py?

Comment: yes it's working in production mode with development server

Comment: line3 of levels/models.py : class Story(models.Model):

Answer (score 2):

i got same problem:
-- first check is you pass dubug to False in production
-- try send your passenger_wsgi.py configuration file here, check if it point django settings correctly
-- verify your different admin file, check if u use correct syntax to register a model. That's was my error, and i didn't know why, my server send me that course of that